# How to spot error in the sentence?

Tags: past-perfect

Is it correct to say"I had left the place when he arrived"?
And what can be the other possible sentences we can frame referring to the same meaning

Comment: Much more appropriate a question for English Language Learners Stack Exchange: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The tense you are using is *past perfect*, also referred to as *pluperfect*. A little research on that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that's technically correct, it's difficult to understand in that order. A better way to phrase it may be

> When he arrived I had already left the place